# Is it okay to have a HOC only for wrapping children in a CSS class in React?

Tags: reactjs

In my project, I have a component and this component has a `Header`. However, the content of this header is different according to the variant of the component (mobile or desktop). So I wonder if is it okay to have a HOC component only for wrapping children in a CSS class ?

For example :

```
export default function MyComponent() {
  return (
    <Header>
      <span>Hello 1</span>
    </Header>    
  )
}

export default function MyComponent2() {
  return (
    <Header>
      <span>Hello 2</span>
    </Header>    
  )
}
```

So the header component would look like this :

```
export default function Header({ children }) {
  return (
    <div className="header">
      {children}
    </div>   
  )
}
```

So basically, the only purpose of the `Header` component is to wrap children in the `header` CSS class.

Comment: As far as technical feasibility, yes, but I think you already know this answer. This might even be helpful down the line if more logic ends up in the header.